# Using HTTP2 directly in NestJS

Tags: javascript, nestjs

Is there any way to use http2 directly in NestJs? (methods like `pushStream` etc) or should i use express for this kind of features?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is none so far. But as long as you have the latest nodejs, you may use the http2 libraries.

You have 2 options:

1. write a [nestjs custom transport](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/custom-transport) (I wonder no one has done that so far)
2. mix it into your code yourself e.g. here a JS http2 client consuming

---

```
const http2 = require('http2')

const session = http2.connect('http://localhost:8088')
    
session.on('error', (err) => console.error(err))

const body = {
                sql: "SELECT * FROM SIGNALS EMIT CHANGES;",
                properties: {"ksql.streams.auto.offset.reset": "latest"}
            }


const req = session.request({
    ':method': 'POST',
    ':path': '/query-stream',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })

req.write(JSON.stringify(body), 'utf8')
req.end()

req.on('response', (headers) => {
  // we can log each response header here
  for (const name in headers) {
    console.log("a header: " + '${name}: ${headers[name]}')
  }
})


req.setEncoding('utf8')
let data = ''
    
req.on('data', (chunk) => { 
    data += chunk 
    console.log('\n${data}')
})
    
req.on('end', () => {
  console.log('\n${data}')      
  session.close()
})
```